# java client example for Kafka Producer, send method not accepting KeyedMessage

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am running kafka 2.9.1-0.8.2.1. I included jars provided in libs/ directory within main kafka directory. Now I am trying to run a java producer example as per what is given here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example. Now `producer.send` method seems to be accepting this kind of argument `Seq<KeyedMessage<String, String>>`. In the example, object of KeyedMessage is not converted into anything. When I try to do the same I get incompatible types compiler error.

Here's the code

```
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;
import java.util.Properties;
import kafka.producer.Producer;
import scala.collection.Seq;

public class KakfaProducer {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
    prop.put("serializer.class","kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
    //prop.put("partitioner.class", "example.producer.SimplePartitioner");
    ProducerConfig producerConfig = new ProducerConfig(prop);
    Producer<String,String> producer = new <String,String>Producer(producerConfig);
    String topic = "test";
    KeyedMessage<String,String> message = new <String,String>KeyedMessage(topic, "Hello Test message");
    producer.send(message);
    producer.close();
  }
}
```

And that commented code is giving me class def not found exception. I tried to look a lot on net, but it's not helping.

There are two kinds of jars in that libs/ directory. One is kafka-client and other one is just kafka and version number. Am I including wrong jar? Which one do I need to work with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first problem, instead of importing scala API, import Java one. 
So, instead of using:

```
import kafka.producer.Producer;
```

please use:

```
import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
```

SimplePartitioner code can be found below. Add it to the corresponding directory:

```
import kafka.producer.Partitioner;
import kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties;

public class SimplePartitioner implements Partitioner {
    public SimplePartitioner (VerifiableProperties props) {
    }

    public int partition(Object key, int numPartitions) {
        int partition = 0;
        String stringKey = (String) key;
        int offset = stringKey.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (offset > 0) {
           partition = Integer.parseInt( stringKey.substring(offset+1)) % numPartitions;
        }
       return partition;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. However this solves my second problem. Could you please help me out with my first problem, issue with producer.send()?

Comment: modified the answer with the solution to first issue.

Comment: awesome that worked! Thanks a lot. Btw can you tell me what's the difference between kafka-client.jar and normal kafka.jar?

Comment: Isn't the recommended producer `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<K,V>`, and not what you've mentioned here? I'm completely new to this, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to run producer in Java.

1) Using core Kafka. Its your method.
2) Using Kafka-client.

The difference between these are mentioned in [Kafka 0.8.2 Documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#uses).

> These new clients are meant to supplant the existing Scala clients, but for compatability they will co-exist for some time. These clients are available in a seperate jar with minimal dependencies, while the old Scala clients remain packaged with the server.

It means the new client is smaller and may replace the original method.

In Section 3.4. New Producer provider some different configs.

> We are working on a replacement for our existing producer. The code is available in trunk now and can be considered beta quality.